# How to format hyperlink in a datatable cell?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, datatable

Why doesn't `string.Format` work with hyperlink in datatable rows?

Example: `mydt.Rows[j][i] = string.Format("<a href='#'>{0}</a>",tmp);`

This gives a string in the cell.

Best regards,
GK

Answer (score 2):

what do you expect?

your datatable is not able to store "hyperlinks" just valuetypes (string, int, datetime ...)

string.Format has nothing todo with hyperlinks. its a String-Formatting-Feature.

how do you visualize your datatable? wpf, asp.net, asp mvc?, win forms?

have you tried this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            Width="212px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("second") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("first");
            table.Columns.Add("second");
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["first"] = "abc";
            dr["second"] = "http://www.abc.com";

            //or dr[0], dr[1]

            table.Rows.Add(dr);

            this.GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: so it is ok, that your datatable just contains a string.
your control needs to know, to output html.
otherwise it will encode it for safe output.

Comment: Tank you very much for answering.  My big problem is that the gridview shows a timetable, first column shows hours form 8-18 and the next columns I fill in a loop with weekdays and dates.  I can't find a way to get hyperlinks into the cells because I don't have static headertext to the columns.

Comment: You also can get your columns by index, see my answer.